# Searching one term in multiple fields with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to search the same text across to fields in my database for a livesearch box.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.username FROM
users AS u, user_invoice AS ui, user_roles AS ur, roles AS r WHERE
u.id = ur.user_id AND
ur.role_id = r.id AND
r.name = 'teacher' AND
(
    ui.user_id = u.id AND
    CAST(ui.invoice AS TEXT) = 'searchterm'
)
```

This query searches the invoice table and returns results properly and extremely quickly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.username FROM
users AS u, user_invoice AS ui, user_roles AS ur, roles AS r WHERE
u.id = ur.user_id AND
ur.role_id = r.id AND
r.name = 'teacher' AND
(u.username like '%searchterm%')
```

This query searches for a matching username and returns extremely quickly as well.

But when I combine the two like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.username FROM
users AS u, user_invoice AS ui, user_roles AS ur, roles AS r WHERE
u.id = ur.user_id AND
ur.role_id = r.id AND
r.name = 'teacher' AND
(
    u.username like '%searchterm%' OR
    (
        ui.user_id = u.id AND
        CAST(ui.invoice AS TEXT) = 'searchterm'
    )
)
```

It returns the proper results but take almost a minute to do so.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:   EXPLAINs of my queries:

First:
http://explain.depesz.com/s/PvS

Second:
http://explain.depesz.com/s/D5c

Combined:
http://explain.depesz.com/s/Dhf

---

Edited for mistake in copying the cast lines.

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Show `explain analyze` output for both please; paste to explain.depesz.com and link to it here.

Comment: You'll probably find out yourself if you rewrite your query into the JOIN-syntax.

Comment: I must agree with wildplasser - it's so much easier to understand what's going on when using `FROM a INNER JOIN b ON (condition)` instead of `FROM a, b WHERE (condition)`. Also, how can the 2nd of the three be producing sensible results? You have a cartesian product from the unconstrained join `ui` in there.

Comment: @CraigRinger : I only counted the where clause terms and it appeared there was one missing. Been there...

Comment: Don't know how the second of the 3 is producing sensible results, but it is.  What's a cartesian product?

Comment: A cartesion product is a join without a condition, like `select * from a,b`. In you case it was *not* a cartesian product. Bonus points for getting us both confused...

Comment: Explains Posted In original post.

Comment: @user1630669 All those queries look like they'll perform REALLY badly on a big `users` table; multiple nested loops over a sequential scan is bad news, though the plans may change as the table grows. I'm not convinced the queries are correct and are really doing what you think, and strongly advise you to convert them to `INNER JOIN` notation. If you pop sample schema and data up on sqlfiddle.com with the queries then it's easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solve this problem in my main app.

I have a main entity that I want users to be able to search for. Call it `customer`. This entity has associated detail records in a 1:n `contact` (for phone, email, etc) table.

I define a view, `customer_quicksearch`, that calculates a quicksearch key - a `text` field containing the concatenation of `contact` records for a customer along with some of the `customer` fields directly.

I've added triggers to `customer` and `contact` `customer_summary` table. The `customer` trigger adds a record to `customer_summary` when a row is inserted into `customer` and delete the row when the `customer` record is deleted. They update `customer_summary` by `SELECT`ing an updated quicksearch key from `customer_quicksearch. I could use a SQL function for this instead of a view, but found the view both more useful and faster. With a view it's quicker to calculate the quicksearch keys for *all* customers, say, after a bulk insert or update.

```
CREATE VIEW customer_quicksearch AS
SELECT
        customer.id AS customer_id, array_to_string(ARRAY[
                customer.code,
                customer.name,
                string_agg(array_to_string(ARRAY[
                        contact.email::text,contact.altemail::text, contact.mobile_phone, contact.work_phone, contact.home_phone, contact.fax
                ],'|'),'|')
        ], '|') AS quicksearch_key
FROM customer
LEFT OUTER JOIN contact ON (customer.id = contact.customer_id)
GROUP BY customer.id;
```

and one of the triggers:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION customer_summary_update_for_contact() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    _customer_id integer;
BEGIN
    -- When a contact is added/removed/changed we have to regenerate the customer search key
    IF tg_op = 'INSERT' OR tg_op = 'UPDATE' THEN
      _customer_id = NEW.customer_id;
    ELSE
      _customer_id = OLD.customer_id;
    END IF;
    UPDATE customer_summary
    SET quicksearch_key = (SELECT quicksearch_key FROM customer_quicksearch WHERE customer_id = _customer_id)
    WHERE customer_id = _customer_id;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
SET search_path = 'public';

CREATE TRIGGER customer_summary_update_for_contact_trg AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON contact
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE customer_summary_update_for_contact();
```

You also need a trigger on `customer` to handle `insert`, `update` and `delete` of customer, maintaining the `customer_summary` record for that customer appropriately.

The `customer_summary` table contains records that include a `quicksearch_key` that's a pipe-concatenation of fields, like:

```
'1800MA|1800 MAKE IT BUILDERS|info@1800makeit.example.com|1234 5678|0499 999 999'
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^
[from customer record]        [from 1st contact record]             [from another contact record]
```

This is searched with a simple `LIKE` pattern. I could add a `text_pattern_ops` index on it for improved performance if I was doing prefix searches, but since I'm mostly doing searches with no left or right anchor - `LIKE '%search%'` - there's no benefit.

Comment: You could use the new trigram index type to make `like '%search%'` use an index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ooh, good point. It's fast enough over the small-ish data set size that it hasn't proved necessary to worry about much in the way of optimisation, but every little bit helps.

Answer (score 0):

No-op (transformed into JOIN syntax) (not an anwer!) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.username 
FROM
users AS u 
JOIN user_invoice AS ui ON u.username like '%searchterm%'
                        OR ( ui.user_id = u.id AND ui.invoice = CAST('searchterm' AS INTEGER))
JOIN user_roles AS ur ON u.id = ur.user_id
JOIN roles AS r ON ur.role_id = r.id
WHERE r.name = 'teacher'
   ;
```

The  `CAST('searchterm' AS INTEGER))` makes no sense to me. Double quotes? parameter?

Comment: searchterm can be alphanumeric, while the field invoice is an integer.  It was throwing an error without the cast, so I left it in there.

Comment: My mistake, I copied the wrong code.  I actually CAST(ui.invoice AS TEXT) = 'searchterm'